# Adding a calculated row based on a boolean condition

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a table as follows:

```
Name | weekNumber  | Status | HoursON
-----|-------------|--------|----------
 M1  |       1     |  False |   12
 M1  |       1     |  True  |    3
 M1  |       1     |  False |    2
 M1  |       2     |  False |   17
 M1  |       2     |  True  |    4
```

If the end of weekNumber ends with a 'False' status, I need to append a row, copying all the column values except 'HoursON' and 'Status. The "Hours-on" value will be subtracted from 24, and 'Status' will be switched to 'True'. In other words, I would prefer the table as follows:

```
Name | weekNumber  | Status | HoursON
-----|-------------|--------|----------
 M1  |       1     |  True  |   12
 M1  |       1     |  True  |    3
 M1  |       1     |  False |    2
 M1  |       1     |  True  |   22    <------ (24 -2 )
 M1  |       2     |  False |   17
 M1  |       2     |  True  |    4    <------ No change
```

I was thinking to execute the operation as follows:

```
def uptimeOffset(x):
   return 24 - x

for elem in df.weekNumber:
    if df.Status[len(df.Status)-1] == 'False':
        df['HoursON'] = df.apply(uptimeOffset(df.HoursON))
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: ("'Series' object is not callable", 'occurred at index HoursON')
```

Can you please provide me how do we approach this issue?

Comment: No, order is not a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `check_last` function to check the last row of each group, add new row with changed `Status` and `HoursON` using `append`

```
In [733]: def check_last(x):
     ...:     last_row = x.iloc[-1]
     ...:     if last_row.Status:
     ...:         return x
     ...:     last_row.Status = True
     ...:     last_row.HoursON = 24 - last_row.HoursON
     ...:     return x.append(last_row)

In [734]: df.groupby('weekNumber').apply(check_last).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[734]:
  Name  weekNumber  Status  HoursON
0   M1           1   False       12
1   M1           1    True        3
2   M1           1   False        2
3   M1           1    True       22
4   M1           2   False       17
5   M1           2    True        4
```

Comment: what does iat[-1] mean to do?

Comment: There is no `iat` in the solution anymore, it's `iloc[-1]` picks that last row of that group `x`

Comment: Thanks for the changes. However, instead of booleans, I have strings actually. For example, False = 'process qual' and True = 'up'. If in 'process qual', then I require to subtract 'HoursON'. However when I run your code, it only does the last row of the table, ie, row 5, where the value is 4.

Comment: It's a trivial change you need to make to above code, try it.

Answer (score 0):

Or You can try

```
df1=df.groupby('weekNumber').nth(-1)[~df.groupby('weekNumber').nth(-1).Status]
df1['HoursON']=24-df1['HoursON']
df1['Status']=True
pd.concat([df,df1.reset_index().set_index(df1.index+len(df)-1)],axis=0)\
    .sort_index().sort_values('weekNumber').reset_index(drop=True)

Out[387]: 
   HoursON  Name   Status  weekNumber
0       12   M1     False           1
1        3   M1      True           1
2        2   M1     False           1
3       22   M1      True           1
4       17   M1     False           2
5        4   M1      True           2
```

Comment: It gives me an error:TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'str'